# Translate a point in 3D according to a distance and an angle

Tags: geometry, transformation

I'm trying to find the coordinates of a point according to this setup:

In a 3 dimensional space, I have a point A(x<sub>A</sub>, y<sub>A</sub>, z<sub>A</sub>) and a point B(x<sub>B</sub>, y<sub>B</sub>, z<sub>B</sub>)

I would like to get the point C, which would be on the intersection between the line AB and a sphere of center A and radius r

[here is a graphical representation of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfAga.png)

I wanted to use basic trigonometry such as Thales theorem but I think it's not practical in 3D. I also looked at matrix but it seems like I need a transformation vector, but all I have are the coordinates of the two points and the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling

$$
\vec v_{AB}= \frac{A-B}{\|A-B\|}
$$

we have

$$
C = A - r\vec v_{AB}
$$

where $r$ is the sphere radius.

Comment: Way more easier than anything I could have thought, thank you !